# Редактор в админке Modx

Tags: modx

Как указать, какой редактор я хочу использовать в админке modx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Системные настройки, параметр `which_editor` `(core - раздел визуальный редактор`) - указать, какой редактор вы будет использовать.

Comment: спасибо большое